# onShowCustomView not invoked by non-html5 videos in 4.4.2

Tags: android-webview

EDIT: It is now clear that the problem is not the the app, but the webpage. A problem that so far only has been spotted in a android-4.4.2-webview.

I have WebViews with a custom WebChromeClient. When something wants to go full screen on a 4.2.2 or 4.3 device the custom WebChromeClient's onShowCustomView is invoked. However with 4.4.2 (specifically I've checked on the devices Nexus 7 and Galaxy S4) it has worked with HTML 5 videos, but flash video plugins trying to go full screen does not invoke onShowCustomView. Other than that the flash video plugins work fine.

I have checked that the WebChromeClient is being added on a 4.4.2 device and it is.

```
public final WebChromeClient fullscreenWebChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
    private View fullscreen = null;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback fullscreenCallback;

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);

        fullscreenCallback = callback;

        if (fullscreenMode) {
            fullscreenCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }

        fullscreen = view;
        fullscreenMode = true;

        pager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        actionbarGestureDetector.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        pageViewWrapper.addView(fullscreen);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        super.onHideCustomView();

        if (! fullscreenMode) {
            return;
        }

        pageViewWrapper.removeView(fullscreen);

        pager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        actionbarGestureDetector.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        fullscreenCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        fullscreen = null;
        fullscreenMode = false;
    }
};
```

Somewhere else:

```
pageWebView.setWebChromeClient(parentActivity.fullscreenWebChromeClient);
```

Comment: How did you get flash working in 4.4? That's totally not supported.

Comment: I was told it was flash. It was not. Instead the ones not working was also a HTML5 video.